# Finding LiDAR data for London Borough of Camden?

Tags: uk

I'm working on creating heights of polygons above terrain level, as in [this blog post](http://blog.nadnerb.co.uk/?p=209), but my area of interest is London Borough of Camden.

[image]

Camden is the green shaded polygon on the map below, generated using the Environment Agency's 1M resolution DTM and DSM LiDAR composites. As can be seen, coverage for Camden and neighbouring Islington is almost completely lacking.

Are there any other data sources that might be available to fill in the gaps?

Comment: This would seem suitable to research/ask at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: It might also be asked over there, but I've looked fairly hard and don't believe there is an Open Data source anywhere to be found - at least not at a decent resolution.

Comment: I only occasionally visit that site but my understanding is that it may be useful for not just finding existing open data, but also for leading to the opening of new data sources.

Comment: Your are out of luck for EA LiDAR coverage for Camden Town, London UK see the area missing here https://houseprices.io/lab/lidar/map?ref=TQ3123585724

Comment: I know EA LiDAR is missing, hence looking for other sources!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, I believe the community is inclined to move on towards this direction, especially on questions about obtaining localized geospatial datasets which carry no additional GIS context or motivation (i.e., the question is solely about having the data). Reference: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/are-questions-about-obtaining-geospatial-data-on-topic

Comment: Happy for it to be migrated. I've actually come across a few sources now but I'll save answering my own question for the other site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LIDAR data of Camden is available as a dated survey. You need to go to http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey/#/survey?grid=TQ28 and scroll down to the LIDAR Tiles 1m 2015. The survey was flown in February 2015 and has not yet been added to the composite data. The new updated composite, with the 2015 data included should be available in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know London that well but this seems like your answer, hard to find the right tile but - http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey/#/survey?grid=TQ28
says it goes down to 50cm, tiles are about 125Mb - let me know how you go

oh, sorry 'bout that - in NZ I've sometimes used manhole cover height data - its a pretty sparse dataset but accurate and better than nothing - wouldn't have a clue how to find that in uk tho'.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the same source. The EA 2M and 1M resolution tiles have the same missing patch, while the 50CM resolution has even worse coverage.

Comment: Manhole height data? How fantastically obscure!

Answer (score 4):

The NERC Airborne Research Facility (https://nerc-arf-dan.pml.ac.uk/) has LiDAR data from 2010 which covers a little of Camden. It is quite a long thin strip, a subset over Camden is shown below.

http://browse.ceda.ac.uk/browse/neodc/arsf/2010/GB08_19

You need to register for an account at CEDA and then apply for access to the ARSF archive before accessing but this should be a quick process.

Only point cloud files are available not gridded DTMs or DSMs but these can be easily generated.

Aerial photography is also available from the same flight.

[image: EA and NERC-ARF LiDAR data for London. Building outlines from Ordnance Survey Open Data]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was planning on answering myself (though less detailed). I'll report back once I've had a dig into what's there. It might be a while though as I've found the building heights data in OS MasterMap which is good enough for the first pass (no roof shapes or trees though).